# Insert, Update values in existing custom table and Select values from that table. Magento2

Tags: magento2, database, sql

How can i Insert, Update values in existing custom table and Select values with Magento methods not sql requests ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have model for your custom table then you do all these stuffs in the below way

Try this,

**Di method :**

Inject your model in your constructor

```
 protected function __construct(
 ....
 \Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ModelName $customTable,
 ....
 )
{
   ...
   $this->customTable = $customTable;
   ...
}
```

then on your execute function from controller

```
execute()
{
  // insert
  $model = $this->customTable->create();
  // update
  $model = $this->customTable->create();
  $model->load('id',$id_to_update);

  $model->setField_Name('values to be stored');
  $model->save();
}
```

In order to get collection

```
$model = $this->customTable->create()->getCollection();
foreach($model as $item){
    echo $item->getFiledName();      
}
```

For more information [Get custom table information](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112291/how-to-get-my-custom-table-data-from-magento-2)

[Save values into custom table](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149368/custom-table-data-not-saving-in-magento-2)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes! Prathap Gunasekaran thank you for good information!