# How to Insert record in database-table through custom module in magento2

Tags: magento2, module, database

I have create a custom module and database-table using following this [steps](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/view-block-layout-template-magento-2.html) and i understand the table displaying in customer_side.

Now I Need to Know the Insert operation in customer_side please give me any example or link for insertion process custom module in magento2.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274903/insert-update-values-in-existing-custom-table-and-select-values-from-that-table/274914#274914

Comment: Thank you for the link

Comment: Thanks for Help...


I Need to Know the Insert and select operation (without use to model) It's Possible or Not?

Comment: Yes possible via sql query in that case you don't model and all just a table to perform actions on it @manoji

Comment: please give me any example or link for insertion and select process without use model in custom module in magento2.

Comment: Ask a separate question may myself or someone will answer to that @manoji

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have model for your custom table then you do all these stuffs in the below way

Try this,

Di method :

Inject your model in your constructor

```
 protected function __construct(
 ....
 \Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ModelName $customTable,
 ....
 )
{
   ...
   $this->customTable = $customTable;
   ...
}
```

then on your execute function from controller

```
execute()
{
  // insert
  $model = $this->customTable->create();
  // update
  $model = $this->customTable->create();
  $model->load('id',$id_to_update);

  $model->setField_Name('values to be stored');
  $model->save();
}
```

In order to get collection

```
$model = $this->customTable->create()->getCollection();
foreach($model as $item){
    echo $item->getFiledName();      
}
```

Hope this helps.
**Copied form** [Insert, Update values in existing custom table and Select values from that table. Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274903/insert-update-values-in-existing-custom-table-and-select-values-from-that-table/274914#274914)

Comment: It's code is working thanks